# Adding methods to a sudsobject. Monkey patching or import to new object?

Tags: python, suds, monkeypatching

I an writing some python code that uses suds to connect up to a device, get the wsdl and query for some device information. That part of the code works and it looks like suds creates and objects and places the data in that object. I would like to add a method to the object, printData, which will print out only the attributes I want, in a specific order and format. I can import the data into a object that I explicitly declare, or write a function, rather than object, but I'm looking to keep it within the object, so other code doesn't need to know about the details, so it is more portable.

There are also other objects, so I really want to just be able to say .print and have it do the right thing (tm) and anyone else who uses the module doesn't have to know or understand the internals.

Now the thing is I can't see to get at the sudsobject Class to add the method. Is monkey patching the way to go, and if so any idea how to get at the sudsobject class so I can add a method or two?

```
>>> response = client.service.exportDevice(context)
>>> a=response[0]
>>> type(a)
<type 'instance'>
>>> dir(a)
['MACAddress', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__getitem__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__keylist__', '__len__', '__metadata__', '__module__', '__printer__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__str__', '__unicode__', 'addressType', 'aliases', 'container', 'description', 'deviceType', 'domainName', 'domainType', 'dupWarning', 'excludeFromDiscovery', 'hostname', 'hwType', 'id', 'ipAddress', 'resourceRecordFlag', 'userDefinedFields']
>>> a.__class__
<class suds.sudsobject.WSDevice at 0x101323940>
>>> b=suds.sudsobject.WSDevice()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WSDevice'
```

Comment: Figured it out, but it won't let me answer it for 7 hours.

Comment: I was able to get it work with the following code:

    >>> def pr(self):
    ...   print self.addressType
    ...   print self.ipAddress
    ... 
    >>> a.__class__.pr = pr
    >>> a.pr()
    Static
    10.30.0.2
    >>> b=response[1]
    >>> b.pr()
    Static
    10.30.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Make a subclass of the object like so:

```
class Subclass(parentClass):
  def newMethod(self):
    print self.someVariableDefinedInTheParentClass
```

Here is a working example:

```
class apple:
  def __init__(self):
    self.color = 'red'

class betterClass(apple):
  def printColor(self):
    print self.color

a = betterClass()
a.printColor()
```

Comment: I am not able to get the Subclass context to work correctly with sudsobjects. The subclass can't be defined until after the suds client connects and suds creates the objects, via the WSDL definitions.